# Adding non-Apple Store eBook to iPhone

Tags: books, macos

I have a number of eBooks (ePub) either from free sources such as Gutenberg, or purchased elsewhere.

I can open them easily enough on my iMac with eBooks, and I gather that they are in my library (when I try to add one manually, it tells me that it’s already there).

On my iPhone, however, I can’t see them at all.

How do I complete the processes?

I will readily consider a third party app.

I have the latest version of all software. In particular, iTunes 12.7, which is of no help to me at all.

Comment: You can just email them to yourself if not too large.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get those books on your iPhone is to open them on the phone. My recommendation is to upload all of those books to a cloud drive, then download them from the drive and then open them via iBooks.